# Python equivalent to Excel Solver: get max value knowing constraints

Tags: python, excel, solver, maximize

I'm quite new to Python and trying to find a Python equivalent to the Excel Solver function.
Let's say I have the following inputs:

```
import math

totalvolflow=150585.6894
gaspercentvol=0.1
prodmod=1224
blpower=562.57
powercons=6

gasvolflow=totalvolflow*gaspercentvol
quantity=math.ceil(gasvolflow/prodmod)
maxpercentvol=powercons*totalvolflow*prodmod/blpower
```

I want to find the maximum value of maxpercentvol by changing gaspercentvol
with the following constraint:

```
quantity*powercon<blpower
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to:

> `maxpercentvol=powercons*totalvolflow*prodmod/blpower`

`maxpercentvol` is 1,965,802.12765274 regardless of the value of `gaspercentvol`.